# What is the difference between "Image Clustering" and "Unsupervised Classification" tasks?

Tags: convolutional-neural-networks, computer-vision, unsupervised-learning, clustering

I am trying to compare some results that I obtained in benchmarks with my unsupervised model. My model basically takes an unlabelled dataset and clusters it into semantic classes (10 clusters in the case of MNIST). However this clustering is done in such a way that a classifier is created (unsupervisedly), as for every image, it outputs a $k$-long vector, with probabilities of being in cluster number $k$.
For evaluation, and because I actually have the labels of the dataset (only to evaluate), I associate every cluster with a class (based on the most assignments to a class per cluster), and calculate an accuracy.

When trying to compare with the MNIST benchmark for instance, I found these two very confusing categories:

On the one hand, we have **Unsupervised Image Classification on MNIST**

https://paperswithcode.com/sota/unsupervised-image-classification-on-mnist

On the other hand, we have **Image Clustering on MNIST-full**

https://paperswithcode.com/sota/image-clustering-on-mnist-full

They record different scores, as if some papers don't qualify for one task but do for the other. At the same time, some papers are in both categories.

What's the difference? I'd really like to know because I'm obtaining State of the Art in this benchmark, and I need to be sure that I'm comparing against the correct papers.

edit: another thing I noticed is that some papers that do classification by clustering images, don't use a test dataset. Why is this allowed? How can they know that the generalization ability of their model is still good?